# How to add assemblies in a 64-bit machine?

Tags: 64-bit, assembly, gac

My old cmd-script:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm blabla.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\GacUtil -i blabla.dll
```

(Which works fine in my old machine.)

But now I have a script for a 64-bit machine (Windows Server 2008 R2):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm blabla.dll
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\GacUtil -i blabla.dll
```

Then I get this message:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm blabla.dll
```

> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility
>   2.0.50727.5420 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.
>
> Types registered successfully

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7 .1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\GacUtil -i blabla.dll
```

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The second command is not successful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote around the path to gacutil because it has spaces in it. Try:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm blabla.dll "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\GacUtil" -i blabla.dll
```